# How to upload file to Google Cloud Filestore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, scp, google-cloud-filestore

I am using [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) and I want to upload HTML file to [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) so it can be consumed by mounted PersistentVolume. However, the Filestore doc is [ambiguous](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/copying-data?hl=it#computer-to-fileshare). I have tried a few variations of the command but I'm getting strange errors not covered by the doc. Here's my Filestore instance:

```
INSTANCE_NAME  ZONE           TIER       CAPACITY_GB  FILE_SHARE_NAME  IP_ADDRESS      STATE  CREATE_TIME
filestore      us-central1-a  BASIC_HDD  1024         filestore        <ADDRESS>  READY  2021-08-15T13:30:39
```

Volume declaration from chart:

```
     volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /filestore
        name: mypvc
```

I don't understand what should I use in scp command for `client-name:/mount-directory`.

Using one of 3 gke instances results `scp: /filestore: Read-only file system`

```
gcloud compute scp /path/to/local/file/index.tmpl gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-b6dd53a7-jtqb:/filestore --project= project
```

Using `filestore-ip:/filestore-path` results `The resource was not found`

commands I also tried:

```
gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-b6dd53a7-jtqb:/mnt/fileshare/
scp: /mnt/fileshare/: Is a directory
--
gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-b6dd53a7-jtqb:/mnt/fileshare/index.tmpl
scp: /mnt/fileshare/index.tmpl: No such file or directory
--
gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-b6dd53a7-jtqb:/mnt/fileshare
scp: /mnt/fileshare: Read-only file system
```

So the main question what should I use here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mount the filestore as a mapped drive and upload to the site and store on mounted drive.

https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean? Should I create a separate VM instance, mount the Filestore to it and then mount from GKE to that VM instance? Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, I am using GE and not GKE but it should work the same